# Will these RAM kits perform differently from eachother?

Tags: pc, memory, desktop

I'm looking to upgrade someone's gaming PC and was wondering if I will notice any difference between these two RAM modules on a Ryzen 5000 CPU. I'd get 4 8GB sticks so the capacity will be the same and both sticks will be from Corsair. I know to some extent timings matter, how tight they are and clock speed matters, but not sure what is more important, timings, latency, or clock speed.

Kit A - 3200mhz CL16, 16-18-18-36 @ 1.35v
Kit B - 3600mhz CL18, 18-19-19-39 @ 1.35v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering it's being run on a Ryzen processor I would reccomend using the 3600mhz kit.
Amd has a thing called Infinity Fabric. You usually want to have this running at a 1:1 ratio of the Ram Base clock. But it's also responsible for some communication within the cpu itself.

By using higher base clock RAM, the Infinity Fabric speeds increase. Causing an overal performance increase of the CPU itself.

Comment: Thanks! I'm more of an Intel guy, so all my world is anything above 3000 is overkill lol